# Post-build event command line

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, build

at the moment I'm working on a WPF solution. I changed the name of the folder that contains the solution and now, when I compile, I have errors regarding the Post-bild event command line.

The command line is:

xcopy $(TargetDir)*.dll $(SolutionDir)SoftwareFactory\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\Modules /y

I imagine that $(SolutionDir) returns a path different from the old one.

How can I change this?

Thanks

Comment: If you replace "xcopy" by "echo" (just for testing), do the paths in the Output window look like you expected them to?

Comment: yes, the path is the new one. when compile I have the error: The command ".." exited with code 4. Any idea?

Comment: Error code 4 can mean "invalid syntax, non-existent path name, or disk full". (E.g. you might have relative path names instead of absolute ones, or there is a space in a path name without surrounding quotes, or the disk really is full.)

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the missing files using the Solution Manager.

After that, add to your solution the Project files, just dragging them from the explorer or using "Add existing project", doing right click on the name of your solution. Browse your project, and click on "Add"

Answer (score 0):

Open `.sln` file in editor(Notepad++) and make sure it contains `new name of solution folder`. If it does not `rename old name of solution folder with new one` manually.